# Retrieving User Uploaded Video Specifications

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, metadata

The web app I'm working on allows a user to upload videos. The videos must meet specific criteria as outlined by our client (format, frame size, frame rate, etc) or they will be rejected.  I found the ffmpeg-php library from some googling.  However, I noticed that it doesn't appear to be actively maintained.

1. What's the current standard library for accessing video data via PHP?
2. If this data is retrieved from the video's metadata, can this information be trusted to be accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg is a good option at: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ffmpeg_movie.php

Or you could use a PHP class, here is one i have found which says "Access media metadata without using the ffmpeg-php library.": http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html

Like most meta datas, they are likely easily editable and untrustworthy.

Comment: It looks like that class is specific to mp3/audio format.  Does it work with other formats & video?

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot that class was for MP3s, I found another one though, hope this ones better!